# Possible to use Tables of same type in Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Lets say I've got an object model, where I have many collections of the same type.

For example something like

```
class StockMarketData {
  List<SummaryData> WeeklySummary;
  List<SummaryData> MonthlySummary;
}

class SummaryData {
  DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
  double Value {get; set;}
}
```

Those lists will map onto database tables.

If you actually use L2S to generate a model from the database you will get something like:

```
class StockMarketData {
      List<WeeklySummaryData> WeeklySummary;
      List<MonthlySummaryData> MonthlySummary;
    }
```

Even though WeeklySummaryData and MonthlySummaryData have the same shape.

Is it possible for Linq to SQL to create tables from a database of summary data, but get each table to contain the same type (such as shown in the top example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario is supported in the designer in the entity framework, but not in the designer (dbml) in linq to sql.

To go down the more manual path, create a class that is not a database entity, called `SummaryData` and populate the class when you Select either the `WeeklySummaryData` or `MonthlySummaryData`. You can then expose properties like this off the DataContext partial class (View Code on the dbml):

```
IQueryable<SummaryData> WeeklySummary
{
    get
    {
        from wsd in WeeklySummaryData
        select new SummaryData { DateTime = wsd.DateTime, Value = wsd.Value }
    }
}

IQueryable<SummaryData> MonthlySummary
{
    get
    {
        from msd in MonthlySummaryData
        select new SummaryData { DateTime = msd .DateTime, Value = msd.Value }
    }
}
```

Comment: Noticed that both methods had the same name - edited so the second is called MonthlySummary